# ActiveRecord query where joined records don't exist

Tags: rails-activerecord

Assuming models like this:

```
Student 
has_many :assignments

Assignment 
belongs_to :student
```

Assignments have a date field "date" representing the date the Assignment was submitted.

How would I, using ActiveRecord query with .where(), retrieve all the Student objects that have no Assignments after date = mm/dd/yyyy?  I prefer to do this with straight ActiveRecord and no database-specific SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [an anti-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29):

```
Student.where("not exists (select 1 from assignments where created_at > ? and assignments.student_id = students.id)", some_date)
```

You can do this with less SQL using the [where_exists gem](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists):

```
Student.where_not_exists(:assignments, "created_at > '#{some_date}'")
```